# SwiftUI NavigationLink producing ghost view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have these three views in my SwiftUI app for navigating from my RideRequestView to the CheckoutView and then to the ReviewOrderView. Once the data is submitted to firebase I make checkoutIsActive to false to pop to the root view. When I do this there is odd behavior as shown in the screen recording. It does pop to the root but it looks like it starts to open a duplicate view of the ReviewOrderView before popping back to root.

Screen Recording: https://youtube.com/shorts/w1AmvhT70gc

```
struct RideRequestView: View {
    var body: some View {

       VStack {
              NavigationLink(isActive: $checkoutIsActive) {
                        CheckoutView(checkoutIsActive: $checkoutIsActive)
              } label: {
                        Button("CONTINUE TO PAYMENT"){
                            Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventBeginCheckout, parameters: nil)
                            checkoutIsActive = true
                        }
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, height: 40)
                        .background(.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        
              }
       }
    }

}
```

CheckoutView

```
struct CheckoutView: View {
    @Binding var checkoutIsActive : Bool
    var body: some View {
NavigationLink(isActive: $reviewOrderIsActive){
                ReviewOrderView($reviewOrderIsActive, checkoutIsActive: $checkoutIsActive)
            } label: {
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        reviewOrderIsActive = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Review Order")
                    }
                }
            }
    }

}
```

ReviewOrderView

```
struct ReviewOrderView: View {
    @Binding var reviewOrderIsActive : Bool
    @Binding var checkoutIsActive : Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            AveRidesMapViewRepresentable()
                
            VStack{
                   Button(action: {
                        submitToFirebase()
                    }){
                        Text("Book Ride")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
private func submitToFirebase () {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
        ref = db.collection("Ride").document()
        ref?.setData([
            //Removed code but stores stuff like price, time, etc.
            
            ]){ err in
                if let err = err {
                   
                } else {
                    self.checkoutIsActive = false
                }
            }
    }
}
```